# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when trying to pull twitter avatar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to pull in user's profile avatars from twitter using these codes

Any idea how I need to fix this error message?

Here's what I'm using in the Users Helper

```
module UsersHelper

def twitteravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
    omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    self.image = omniauth['info']['image'].sub("_normal", "_bigger")
    gravatar_url = self.image
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name)
  end
end
```

Then I'm trying to use this in view and pull the user's individual avatar

```
<%= link_to twitteravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
```

Is it because I can't use `request.env['omniauth.auth']` in helper?

Answer (score 0):

One value of the chain will be nil

```
request.env['omniauth.auth']['info']['image']
```

Use puts to determine which one

```
puts request.env['omniauth.auth']
```

For example, perhaps omniauth['info']['image'] is nil because the user doesn't have an image set?

Comment: how should the user table be set up? I only added a new column called "image".

Answer (score 0):

A good way to check is

```
img = request.env.try('[]','omniauth.auth').try('[]','info').try('[]','image')
```

The answer of this is the correct img or nil if something went wrong in the middle.